# Maths with arrays, can I calculate values inside an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, class

Please, I need help to make this script work.

I dont know if I can make maths with an string.

I need a program that save numbers inside an array and after that i need to calculate the average betwen those numbers.

When trying to compile this program the compiler only gives me this message:

```
Basquete2.java:6: error: illegal start of expression
        private Pontos [] pontos;
        ^
1 error
```

And this is the complete Script:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Basquete {
 public static void main(String[]args){
    //criando array nulo
    private Pontos [] pontos;
    //variaveis
    String desicaoUsuario = "sim";
    int i = 0;
    int pos = -1;
    int soma = 0;
    int divisor = 0;
    float media;

    while(desicaoUsuario == "sim" ){

            if(pontos == null){
                //criando array
                pontos = new Pontos[1];
                //posicionando
                pos = 0;
                //inserindo dados pelo usuario na posiçao
                pontos[pos] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o número:");
                //pergunta se deseja continuar
                desicaoUsuario = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Deseja adicionar outro número? sim/nao");
            }else{
                //criando novo array guardando os objetos
                Pontos [] backup = pontos;
                //ampliando o array original
                pontos = new Pontos[pontos.lenght + 1];
                //copiando objetos para o array original
                    for(int i = 0; i < backup.lenght; i++){
                    pontos[i] = backup[i];
                    }
                //posicionando
                pos = backup.lenght;
                //ciando objeto na posição pronta para inserir
                pontos[pos] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe o número:");
                //pergunta se deseja continuar
                desicaoUsuario = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Deseja adicionar outro número? sim/nao");
                }
    }

    //mostrando mensagem
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Vamos calcular a media de pontos do time por partida!");

    //calculando soma
    i = 0;
    while(i < pontos.lenght){
        soma = soma + pontos[i];
        i++;
    }
    //calcula media
    divisor = pontos.lenght;
    media = soma / divisor;
    //mostra resultado da media
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("A media de pontos é de " + media + " pontos por partida!");
    //saida do sistema
    System.exit(0);

 }
}
```

Comment: How about removing `private`, then?

Comment: Local variables can't have an access modifier (private, public, protected).

Comment: Local variables can only be used within the method where they're declared.  In fact, sometimes their scope is even smaller than that.  So they're not just `private`, they're kind of super extra private.  And because you can't change that behaviour (that is, they can never be `public` or anything else), there's no point putting any kind of access modifier on them.  So you need to remove the word `private` from that line of code.  It simply doesn't make any sense for it to be there.

Comment: @Li357 I missed that  time to hit the hay...